# Django + Gunicorn + Nginx. 404

Tags: django, nginx

I am trying to run django + gunicorn + nginx locally.

For some reason nginx is not getting data from static. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Gunicorn:

`gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8001`

Nginx config:

```
# mysite_nginx.conf
upstream project_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen 80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name localhost; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/ferom/Programming/my_avatar_clock/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ferom/Programming/my_avatar_clock/my_avatar_clock/proj/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

Folders:

[image]

In settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

But when I open `http://127.0.0.1/admin/`

Nginx say me: 404.

`cat /var/log/nginx/error.log` - empty

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you unicorn port was not the same on the Nginx file. I recommend you try set the same port, on the Gunicorn and Nginx proxy.

you say that Gunicorn command was on port 8001:

```
gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8001
```

But you nginx file was proxy on port 8000:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
```